# Toolbox Design in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I want to implement a toolbox control in WPF.
(As you can see in the picture its kind of mspaint toolbox)
Clicking on a one of the buttons can effect some of the other button's  state while it doesn't effect the rest of them. I've tried to show my point with the different colors.
If you click the first red button and than another red button, they both reamin as clicked.
but if you click another button it turns the red buttons state of.

So my question is about architecture, is there a good known design for managing the statuses of the buttons, suprting the different groups in it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you would benefit from the "Observer Pattern". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

The Subject would be the Toolbox and the Observers would be the buttons inside of the Toolbox. It makes it very easy to manage the states of the buttons - I've used it for similar purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a class that represented the state (which could be written much better than here). And use INotifyPropertyChanged and Binding to control the state of the buttons. I'm not entirely convinced this is a "great" way of doing it. But it is one way (and I think it might tie a little into the observer pattern mentioned in another answer).

First the class that represents the state:

```
public class ControlState : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool _redOneChecked;
  public bool RedOneChecked { 
    get { return _redOneChecked; }
    set
    {
      OnPropertyChanged("RedOneChecked");
      _redOneChecked = value;
      RedTwoChecked = RedOneChecked;
      GreenOneChecked = !RedTwoChecked;
    }
  }

  private bool _redTwoChecked;
  public bool RedTwoChecked
  {
    get { return _redTwoChecked; }
    set
    {
      OnPropertyChanged("RedTwoChecked");
      _redTwoChecked = value;
      RedOneChecked = RedTwoChecked;
      GreenOneChecked = !RedTwoChecked;
    }
  }

  private bool _greenOneChecked;
  public bool GreenOneChecked
  {
    get { return _greenOneChecked; }
    set
    {
      OnPropertyChanged("GreenOneChecked");
      _greenOneChecked = value;
      RedOneChecked = !GreenOneChecked;
      RedTwoChecked = !GreenOneChecked;
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

And then data-binding the UI controls:

```
var state = new ControlState();
controlRedOne.DataBindings.Add("Checked", state, "RedOneChecked");
```